# Prove $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{3a\sin^2\theta}{(1-a\cos \theta)^4}\mathrm{d}\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos \theta}{(1-a\cos \theta)^3}\,\mathrm{d}\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

While doing some mathematical modelling of planetary orbits I have come up with two definite integrals $D_1$ and $D_2$ which appear to produce the same result when I test (using www.WolframAlpha.com) for various values of $a$  where $0<a<1$.
$$
D_1
\, =\,
\int_0^{2\pi}f_1\,\mathrm{d}\theta
\, =\,
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{3a\sin^2\theta}{(1-a\cos \theta)^4}\mathrm{d}\theta
\,=\,
\frac{3a\pi}{(1-a^2)^{5/2}}
\, =\,R
$$
and
$$
D_2
\, =\,
\int_0^{2\pi}f_2\,\mathrm{d}\theta
\, =\,
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos \theta}{(1-a\cos \theta)^3}\,\mathrm{d}\theta
\, =\,
\frac{3a\pi}{(1-a^2)^{5/2}}
\, =\,R
$$

---

How could I go about proving:-

(1) $D_1$ = $D_2$,

(SOLVED, I think, by my two answers below, but using WolframAlpha to obtain integral solutions)
$$$$

(2) $D_1$ = $R$ or $D_2$ = $R$.

(MOVED to a separate question:
[Prove $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{3a\sin^2\theta}{(1-a\cos \theta)^4}$ or $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos\theta}{(1-a\cos\theta)^3}=\frac{3a\pi}{(1-a^2)^{5/2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990813/prove-int-02-pi-frac3a-sin2-theta1-a-cos-theta4-or-int-02-pi)).

---

**UPDATE 1**

You can see how [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/)
produces these results by inputting the following input texts:-

For Eqtn 1 with a=0.1 input: integrate (3*0.1(sinx)^2)/((1-0.1*cosx)^4) from x=0 to 2*pi

For Eqtn 2 with a=0.1 input: integrate (cosx)/((1-0.1*cosx)^3) from x=0 to 2*pi

for Result with a=0.1 input: evaluate 3 *0.1* pi/(1-0.1^2)^(5/2)

---

**UPDATE 2**

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/) also computes expressions for the *indefinite* integrals as follows:-
$$I_1
\, =\,
\int\frac{3a\sin^2\theta}{(1-a\cos \theta)^4}\mathrm{d}\theta
\,=\,
$$
$$constant1 + \frac
{a\,\sqrt{a^2-1}\sin\theta\,[-(2a^3+a)\cos^2\theta+3(a^2+1)cos\theta+a(2a^2-5)]}
{2(a^2-1)^{5/2}(a\cos\theta-1)^3}
$$

$$-\frac
{6a\,(a\cos\theta-1)^3\,\tanh^-1
\left(
\frac{(a+1)\tan(\theta/2)}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}
\right)
}
{(2(a^2-1)^{5/2}\,(a\cos\theta-1)^3}
$$
$$$$
$$$$

$$I_2
\, =\,
\int\frac{\cos \theta}{(1-a\cos \theta)^3}\,\mathrm{d}\theta
\, =\,
$$
$$constant2 -
\frac
{2a^2\sin\theta-sin\theta}
{2(a^2-1)^2(a\cos\theta-1)}
-\frac
{\sin\theta}
{2(a^2-1)(a\cos\theta-1)^2}
$$

$$
-\frac
{3a\tanh^-1\left(\frac{(a+1)\tan(\theta/2)}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)}
{(a^2-1)^{5/2}}
$$
Note that the final terms of each expression are equivalent to each other.  This could be useful. For example we can define a *difference* function $f_3 = f_1-f_2$ whose indefinite integral $I_3 = I_1-I_2$ will exclude the common awkward third term.

Let us assume that $f_3$ is continuously integrable over the range $0,2\pi$ (we cannot be sure by inspection alone, but it can be shown, see my answer below).  Then, if $D_1=D_2$ over the range $0,2\pi$ then $D_1-D_2=0$ and so $D_3$ (=$\int_0^{2\pi}f_3\,d\theta$) should have value zero.  This is expanded on in my answer below.

Comment: Have you taken any Complex Analysis class?

Comment: $${\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right) \over \left[1 - \cos\left(\theta\right)\right]^{4}} \sim {16 \over \theta^{6}}\ \mbox{when}\ \theta\sim 0$$. Do they converge ?.

Comment: Can you include some of your WA testing? As Felix has just indicated, there are problems of convergence with these integrals...

Comment: Apologies, I missed a factor "a" from the LHS denominators. Now corrected.

Comment: You can at least prove that the two integrals are equal by a simple integration by parts, though this doesn't tell you what the value is.

Comment: @Yiorgos. Nope, my maths level is pre-university.

Comment: @Felix. I missed a factor "a" from the LHS denominators, now corrected.

Comment: @Semiclassical. I missed a factor "a" from the LHS denominators, now corrected. Also added examples of inputs to Wolfram alfa to the question.

Comment: @David H. I am trying your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(as per David H's suggestion to use Integration By Parts)

Hypothesis: The two definite integrals $D_1$ and $D_2$ have the same value, i.e. $D_1 = D_2$.

Using integration by parts
$$
\int uv' \,d\theta= uv-\int u'v \,d\theta
$$
let us define 
$$
u = \frac{1}{(1-a\cos\theta)^3}
\qquad
v' = \cos\theta
$$
So ($u'$ obtained from WolframAlpha)
$$
u'=\frac{-3a\sin\theta}{(1-a\cos\theta)^4}
\qquad
v=\sin\theta
$$
Then 
$$
\int\frac{\cos\theta}{(1-a\cos\theta)^3}\,d\theta= uv - \int u'v\, d\theta
$$

$$=\frac{-\sin\theta}{(1-a\cos\theta)^3}
-\int \frac{-3a\sin^2\theta}{(1-a\cos\theta)^4}
$$
So
$$\int\frac{\cos\theta}{(1-a\cos\theta)^3}\,d\theta=
\frac{-\sin\theta}{(1-a\cos\theta)^3}
+\int \frac{3a\sin^2\theta}{(1-a\cos\theta)^4}\,d\theta.
$$
Now consider the definite integrals over the range $0,2\pi$

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos\theta}{(1-a\cos\theta)^3}\,d\theta=
\left[\frac{-\sin\theta}{(1-a\cos\theta)^3}\right]_0^{2\pi}
+\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{3a\sin^2\theta}{(1-a\cos\theta)^4}\,d\theta
$$
The term in square brackets clearly goes to zero over the range $0,2\pi$ because $\sin(0)=\sin(2\pi)=0$ and therefore we have $D_1=D_2$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Observe that,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left[\frac{1}{\left(1-a\cos{\theta}\right)^2}\right]=\frac{2\cos{\theta}}{\left(1-a\cos{\theta}\right)^3}.$$

Thus, we can simplify the integral we have to compute via the technique of differentiating under the integral sign:

$$\begin{align}
I(a)
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos{\theta}}{\left(1-a\cos{\theta}\right)^3}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left[\frac{1}{\left(1-a\cos{\theta}\right)^2}\right]\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac12\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\left(1-a\cos{\theta}\right)^2}.\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks. I am reading up on "differentiation under the integral" and hopefully will apply it in my separate answer. But maybe instead use d/da[1/(1 - a cos \theta)^3]?

Comment: Differentiation under the integral is beyond my present ability so I have "cheated" and used WolframAlpha (see my answer). I would be interested to see how d-u-t-i can be applied to this problem but it looks like it will be a lot of effort. Cheers :-). –

Comment: Aha, I was thinking this hint referred to integrating by parts (your earlier comment) but now I see IBP solves the first part of the problem, quite simply. I will do another answer based on IBP (unless you would like to do it yourself?).

Answer (score 1):

METHOD

Consider whether the Difference Function   $\,f_3=f_1-f_2$  integrates to zero over the interval $0,2\pi$.  If it does then $D_1 = D_2$.

SUMMARY

The difference function does integrate to zero over the given interval.  Therefore the two definite integrals $D_1$ and $D_2$ are equal.

DETAIL

Let us try to prove the hypothesis that the two definite integral expressions $D_1$, $D_2$ are equal for all values of $a$ (where $0<a<1$), i.e.
$$
D_1=
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{3a\sin^2\theta}{(1-a\cos \theta)^4} d\theta
=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(1-a \cos\theta)\cos \theta}{(1-a\cos \theta)^4}d\theta
=D_2
$$

Let us define functions $f_1$, $f_2$ and their respective indefinite integrals $I_1$ and $I_2$ such that
$$
I_1(a,\theta) 
= \int f_1(a,\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\theta
=\int\frac{3a\sin^2\theta}{(1-a\cos \theta)^4} d\theta
$$
and
$$I_2(a,\theta) = \int f_2(a,\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\theta
=\int\frac{(1-a \cos\theta)\cos \theta}{(1-a\cos \theta)^4}d\theta
$$

---

WolframAlpha gives us for the indefinite integrals $I_1$ and $I_2$
$$I_1(a,\theta)
\, =\,
\int\frac{3a\sin^2\theta}{(1-a\cos \theta)^4}\mathrm{d}\theta
\,=\,
$$
$$constant1 + \frac
{a\,\sqrt{a^2-1}\sin\theta\,[-(2a^3+a)\cos^2\theta+3(a^2+1)cos\theta+a(2a^2-5)]}
{2(a^2-1)^{5/2}(a\cos\theta-1)^3}
$$

$$-\frac
{6a\,(a\cos\theta-1)^3\,\tanh^-1
\left(
\frac{(a+1)\tan(\theta/2)}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}
\right)
}
{(2(a^2-1)^{5/2}\,(a\cos\theta-1)^3}
$$
and
$$I_2(a,\theta)
\, =\,
\int\frac{\cos \theta}{(1-a\cos \theta)^3}\,\mathrm{d}\theta
\, =\,
$$
$$constant2 -
\frac
{2a^2\sin\theta-sin\theta}
{2(a^2-1)^2(a\cos\theta-1)}
-\frac
{\sin\theta}
{2(a^2-1)(a\cos\theta-1)^2}
$$

$$
-\frac
{3a\tanh^-1\left(\frac{(a+1)\tan(\theta/2)}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)}
{(a^2-1)^{5/2}}
$$

---

If the functions $I_1$ and $I_2$ were continuous over the interval $0,2\pi$ we could simply test whether the following statement is true: $$I_1(a,2\pi) - I_1(a,0) = I_2(a,2\pi) - I_2(a,0)$$ 
However the functions $I_1$ and $I_2$ are not continuous over the interval $0,2\pi$.  This is  due to the incorporation, in both of these functions, of the awkward term involving $\tanh^1()$ and $\tan(\theta/2)$ which produces a singularity when $\theta/2 = \pi/2$.

---

As an alternative approach let us obtain the function $I_3$ which is the indefinite integral of the  *Difference* *Function* $f_3$   defined by $$f3(a,\theta) =f1(a,\theta)-f2(a,\theta)$$

As mentioned in the Question ( Update 2 ) subtraction of $I_2$ from $I_1$ will eliminate from $I_3$ the awkward final term in $\tanh^-1()$ which is common to both $I_1$ and $I_2$. Presumably then, although I haven't proved it, we could find a simple expression for $I_3$ by algebraic rationalisation of $I_1 - I_2$.

Conveniently however, when given the formula for $I_3$, WolframAlpha returns a simple result thus

$$I_3(a,\theta) = \int\frac{3a\sin^2\theta - \cos \theta(1-a \cos\theta)}
{(1-a\cos \theta)^4} d\theta
=\frac{sin\theta}{(a\cos\theta-1)^3}+ constant3
$$

Now, to prove that $D_1=D_2$ we simply need to show that $D_3=0$.  This can be done by showing that $I_3(a,2\pi)-I_3(a,0) = 0$.

Knowing that $\sin(2\pi)=\sin(0)=0$ and that   $\cos(2\pi)=\cos(0)=1$, it is simple to show that

$$
I_3(a,2\pi)=\frac{sin(2\pi)}{(a\cos(2\pi)-1)^3}+ constant3= 0+ constant3
$$
and
$$
I_3(a,0)=\frac{sin(0)}{(a\cos(0)-1)^3}+ constant3= 0+ constant3
$$
So
$$
I_3(a,2\pi)-I_3(a,0) = 0+ constant3 -(0+ constant3) = 0
$$
Therefore the original hypothesis is confirmed:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{3a\sin^2\theta}{(1-a\cos \theta)^4} d\theta
=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(1-a \cos\theta)\cos \theta}{(1-a\cos \theta)^4}d\theta
$$

$$D_1=D_2$$.

Note: Part (2) of the question is not answered by this.